# How to acquire tf.data.dataset's shape?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I know dataset has output_shapes, but it shows like below:

> data_set: DatasetV1Adapter shapes: {item_id_hist: (?, ?), tags: (?, ?), client_platform: (?,), entrance: (?,), item_id: (?,), lable: (?,), mode: (?,), time: (?,), user_id: (?,)}, types: {item_id_hist: tf.int64, tags: tf.int64, client_platform: tf.string, entrance: tf.string, item_id: tf.int64, lable: tf.int64, mode: tf.int64, time: tf.int64, user_id: tf.int64}

How can I get the total number of my data?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Where the length is known you can call:

```
tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset)
```

but if this fails then, it's important to know that a TensorFlow `Dataset` is (in general) lazily evaluated so this means that in the general case we may need to iterate over every record before we can find the length of the dataset.

For example, assuming you have eager execution enabled and its a small 'toy' dataset that fits comfortably in memory you could just `enumerate` it into a new list and grab the last index (then add 1 because lists are zero-indexed):

```
dataset_length = [i for i,_ in enumerate(dataset)][-1] + 1
```

Of course this is inefficient at best and, for large datasets, will fail entirely  because everything needs to fit into memory for the list. in such circumstances I can't see any alternative other than to iterate through the records keeping a manual count.

Comment: The following should allow this to work for datasets of any size (although it would still be horribly inefficient) since you would only consume one item at a time from the generator:  dataset_length = 1 + max(i for i, _ in enumerate(dataset))

Answer (score 3):

Code as below:

```
dataset_to_numpy = list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
shape = tf.shape(dataset_to_numpy)
print(shape)
```

It produces output like this:

```
tf.Tensor([1080   64   64    3], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```

It's simple to write the code, but it still costs time to iterate the dataset.
For more info about `tf.data.Dataset`, check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#as_numpy_iterator).

Answer (score 2):

As of 4/15/2022 with the TF v2.8, you can get the results by using

`dataset.cardinality().numpy()`

ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cardinality

Answer (score 0):

*To see element shapes and types, print dataset elements directly instead of using as_numpy_iterator.* - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3])
for element in dataset:
  print(element)
```

break from for loop to see the shape of any tensor

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_s, y_s))
for element in dataset:
  print(element)
  break
```

Output here as two numpy arrays and shape of each is printed

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(13,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([ 0.9521966 ,  0.68100524,  1.973123  ,  0.7639558 , -0.2563337 ,
        2.394438  , -1.0058318 ,  0.01544279, -0.69663054,  1.0873381 ,
       -2.2745786 , -0.71442884, -2.1488726 ], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 1.], dtype=float32)>)
```