# Number of distinct labels and input data shape in tf.data Dataset

Tags: tensorflow

The [Tensorflow Fashion-MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) tutorial is great... but it seems clear you have to know **in advance** that there are 10 distinct labels in the dataset, and that the input data is image data of size 28x28. I would have thought these details should be readily discoverable from the dataset itself - is this possible? Could I discover the same information the same way on a quite different dataset (e.g. the [Titanic Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data), which comprises M rows by N columns of CSV data, and is a binary classification task). [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) does not appear to have any obvious `get_label_count()` or `get_input_shape()` functions in its API. Call me a newbie, but this suprises/confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218014/how-to-acquire-tf-data-datasets-shape), Tensorflow `tf.data.Dataset` instances are **lazily evaluated**, meaning that you could, in principle, need to iterate the through an entire dataset to establish the number of distinct labels, and the input data shape(s) (which can be variable, for example with variable-length sequences of sound or text).